# How to hide subfolder in url

Tags: html, .htaccess, cpanel, whm

I installed whm and cpanel in my server. In order to get access to cpanel, I created a user named admin. Everytime I go to my website, I have to type in the url plus the user name, http://ubawareta.com/~admin. But I want to change it to the way that the url is solely http://ubawareta.com/
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable mod_userdir in WHM. Security Center -> Apache mod_userdir Tweak. Disable apache mod_user dir. These way you won't be able to access the cPanel accounts using http://server-ip/~cpanel_user